# How to set up a contextual filter or child relationship?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

Every now and then I'm re-attempting to set up a decent taxonomy explorer/browser. I have already managed to customize a tpl file for that (oh, I know, tpl should not contain advanced logic, some day I'll learn how to do that properly). Now I decided to give it a shot using Views. While I managed to set up a view for the top-level listing, now I'm trying to set up a decent lower-level browser.
I don't think it's possible, but maybe you will prove to me that it is.
My taxonomy has a very simple structure in that **at a given level it has only branches or leaves, never are they mixed**. Now, at some level (the depth is variable at different branches), the branches end and the leaves are to be listed. Therefore I'd thought this logic would be appropriate:

```
on page taxonomy/term/%
list items which
(a) belong to vocab X
and ((b1) are either children of parent with tid=%1
(b2) or are published nodes of content type Y with term tid=%1 assigned.)
```

For (b1) I have defined a parent term relationship and used it as a contextual filter. This alone works, but I don't know how to set up the b2 part. Can I re-use the same part of URL for another or'ed contextual filter. The '%1' string does not seem to work when entered in the filter section. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to solve it using contextual filters and relationships. I solved the b2 part by using a separate dedicated view of content nodes as a No results view. It works because the taxonomy has consistent, non-mixed level contents.